# How to change xorg.conf file with permission?

Tags: command-line, xorg, permissions

I want to edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file but I can't save the file. It says "permission denied."

How can I edit the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a Terminal and then :

**Open with Gedit...**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

**open with nano...**

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

now you can edit ..

P.D make a backup before change the file so you can revert your modification...

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf_backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're trying to edit the file without permissions. First make a backup of your file in case something goes wrong.

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf{,.bk}
```

Then, you can edit the file with you text editor, for example

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And save it.

Comment: You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as Root -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo