# no brightness control on macbookpro 7.1 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: brightness

i have been trying to fix my brightness issue on my macbookpro 7.1 running snow leopard tried almost all suggestions. but nothing worked. tried modifying xorg.conf but it tells me i dont have permission to do so. tried different drivers and reinstalling the unit and nothing seemed to work.

if anyone can put me out of my misery i will be so happy :) im literally spending my second week trying to fix this.

i downgraded from 12.10 hoping that this issue would have been fixed in a lower update :(

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of another question.

I have brightness problems as well and have not yet found a solution, but are you sure you've checked the many other brightness questions on here before posting your question?  for example did you try the following:

[Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610#57610)

% Note that since that question was for a lenovo, instead of "acpi_video0" yours will probably be "apple_backlight" - but check first as specified in that link.

If that doesn't work there are a number of other suggested fixes on the boards.

And - I know this is kind of a stupid question - but when you say you couldn't modify xorg.cong, you did use the command "sudo gedit [path]" to give yourself root access...right?  If you still don't have permission then you've probably somehow messed up your write permissions and will need to use chmod to return write permission to those folders: which info is also available in responses to other questions.

Comment: hello i found a fix.i wasnt able to edit xorg.conf file. i was constantly denied permission to edit until i followed the commands here

http://askubuntu.com/questions/69392/how-to-change-xorg-conf-file-with-permission

then i did what was suggested on this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/222801/brightness-control-not-working-ubuntu-12-04-lts-macbook-pro-5-5/259046#259046

just for reference im using a macbookpro 7.1 running snow leopard 10.7 

thank you i was looking for a solution for two weeks.